# bending a cylinder

Tags: modeling

How does one use the bend option in *Objects > Transform > Bend* (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd> ) in *Object mode*.

I'm migrating from 3DS Max, I have used the *Simple Deform Modifier*, works great whether I'm in *Edit* or *Object mode*.

Bend works in *Edit mode* but in *Object mode* it just flips my simple cylinder with many loops around the 3D Cursor without bending it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, there are *many* ways to bend a cylinder. One good one is this:

1) Use the *curve* modifier. This is how to: Add a curve by going to **add > curve > any** it doesn't matter what curve you add. Select the cylinder, and go to edit mode. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, and before selecting anything, scroll your mouse wheel so that it adds around 100-200 loop cuts around the circumference.

Now, you can adjust your curve any way in edit mode too, for it will be the basis for the deformation of the cylinder. Select the cylinder once you are done, and add a *curve* modifier. Set the deform curve to your curve, and move the cylinder so that it is positioned around the curve. It should be deforming currently. If you want it to keep that position forever, then apply the modifier. If you want to animate it, then don't. Here's a picture of a nicely curved cylinder using *curve* modifier:

[image]